# Can't access server with ssh without password using source root user

Tags: ssh

**To be clear:** I am trying to access the server using my root account and not the server's root account (all the questions out there are the other way around).

**Reason:** I want to run a rsync script in a cron to backup all my files and I need to do this as root to get all files.

**Problem:** When I am trying to `ssh regularuser@server` it keeps asking me for the server's  password even though I have set the proper ssh keys. It's working without issue on my regular account but not *from* root and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Do you have the keys in `root`s home directory?

Comment: yes, I have used ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id from the root account and all the keys are in /root/.ssh/. The server has the proper root:computer key in authorized_keys. I am assuming perhaps a setting is missing in the root's config? But don't know where

Comment: Does it work if you explicitly pass the key with `-i`? If not, include the output of `ssh -vvv [...]` in your question by editing

Comment: I have ran `ssh -vvv` and it was looking for default file names, while I have provided a custom namefor the key. Using -i works just fine but now it asks me for the passphrase because it was stored in gnome keyring. I guess I'll just create a new key without a passphrase. Thank you!!!